# JQuery: How to change CSS of elements that are with a certain element in one group

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to know how I could change the CSS of all the `<li>` tags within `<ul class='dropdown-menu'>` that has the `<a href='' class='dropdown-toggle about-header'>` using JQuery? Please help me.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:return false" class="dropdown-toggle about-header" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="icon-info"></span> About the Province</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="javascript:return false" class="demographics">Demographics</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:return false" class="other">Other Info</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:return false" class="about">About the <span class='demonym'></span></a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:return false" class="lgu">Local Government Unit</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:return false" class="dropdown-toggle update-header" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="icon-refresh"></span> Provincial Updates</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="javascript:return false" class="news">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:return false" class="event">Events</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you want to find all the `<li>` tags within `<ul class='dropdown-menu'>` that has `<a href='' class='dropdown-toggle about-header'>` preceding it?

If so, this will work: `'a.about-header ~ ul.dropdown-menu li'`

To break down the pseudo selector,

- `a`  = find a link
- `.about-header` = that has the "about-header" class
- `~` = get that element's next sibling
- `ul` but only if it's an unordered list
- `.dropdown-menu` = that has the class "dropdown-menu"
- `li` return all the list items contained in the matched element

```js
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){ 

  var clas = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1]; 
  
  $('.'+clas+' ~ ul.dropdown-menu li').toggle();  // using toggle here lets a second click on the element re-hide the `li`s 
  
  // $('.'+clas).next('.dropdown-menu').find('li').toggle();  // you could also do it this way
  
  // $('.'+clas+' ~ ul.dropdown-menu li').`.css({ visibility : 'visible', display : 'block' });

});
```

```css
ul.dropdown-menu li{
    display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle about-header" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="icon-info"></span> About the Province</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="#" class="demographics">Demographics</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="other">Other Info</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="about">About the <span class='demonym'></span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="lgu">Local Government Unit</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle update-header" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="icon-refresh"></span> Provincial Updates</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#" class="news">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="event">Events</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
```

Comment: This solved my problem. My current script is 
`$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
 var clas = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
 $('.'+clas+'  ~ ul.dropdown-menu').css({
  visibility : 'visible',
  display : 'block'
 });
});`
Thanks mate!

Comment: For grins, I incorporated your additional code into my answer

Comment: You should change all of the `href="javascript:return false"` in your html to `href="#"`. As is you get a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement` error in the console every time a user clicks one of those links. I would also suggest that you use `toggle()` instead of `.css({ visibility : 'visible', display : 'block' });` this way clicking on the header again will re-hide the `li`s. But only if you want that behaviour

Answer (score 0):

## [*DEMO CHANGING CSS*](http://jsfiddle.net/zoq6jjt8/)

You can use `[href=].dropdown-toggle.about-header` ,then find the parent `li` and hide it.

```js
$("a[href=''].dropdown-toggle.about-header").parent("li").hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li>
  <a href='' class='dropdown-toggle about-header'>hide</a>
</li>
  
<li>
  <a class='dropdown-toggle about-header'>don't hide me</a>
</li>
```

or from `dropdown-menu`

```
 $(".dropdown-menu").find("a[href=''].dropdown-toggle.about-header").parent("li").hide()
```

Full demo

```js
$(".dropdown-menu").find("a[href=''].dropdown-toggle.about-header").parent("li").hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='dropdown-menu'>
    <li>
      <a href='' class='dropdown-toggle about-header'>hide</a>
    </li>
      
    <li>
      <a class='dropdown-toggle about-header'>don't hide me</a>
    </li>
<ul>
```